# Redux Action data needed for another Action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

so I have an Action, which fetches some data from rest. In a component, i need this data from the fetch, which is set in store. 
I use this data then like `someFunc(this.props.data)` in `componentDidMount()`. Afterwards i give the return value of `someFunc` an another Action, which does something with this data and also sets it in store.

My only idea is, to give `someFunc` to the Action as a callback and call this right after the first data is fetched. So i have 2 dispatched in one action.

I hope you guys understand what i mean. Is there a better way to do this?

## Edit

In Component1 i dispatch an Action, which loads data i need to the store. In Component2 i dispatch another Action, which gets his value from `someFunc` function. But `someFunc` gets the data from the first Action, so the data is undefined when i call `someFunc`, because the data isn't set in the store yet.

More clear yet?

## Component1

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.props.dataLoadAction()   //action for the fetch i told
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {
        dataLoadAction: () => {
            dispatch(dataLoadAction())
        }
    }
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component1);
```

## Component2

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.props.changeDataAction(this.someFunc(this.props.data))
}

render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.otherData}
            </div>
        )
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        otherData: state.someReducer.otherData,
        data: state.someReducer.data,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {
        changeDataAction: (changedData) => {
            dispatch(changeDataAction(changedData))
        }
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component2);
```

## Actions

```
export function dataLoadAction(){
    return dispatch => {

    HttpRequest.getJson("some url", json => {

            dispatch(
                {
                    type: 'DATA_LOADED',
                    payload: {
                        data: json
                    }
                }
            )
        });
    });
};
```

}

```
export function changeDataAction(changedData){
    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(
            {
                type: 'LOAD_CHANGEDDATA',
                payload: mappedVis
            }
        )

    };
}
```

Comment: Could you post more detailed code samples showing how you're doing it now? It's hard to understand how to help without more details about the situation.

Comment: @MarkChandler i tryed to insert some code, but i have to leave much code out. I hope its still clear..

Comment: Try to use promises, so that after one action returns you can call another function with updated store.

Comment: How with promises?